# Line graphical component

Tags: java, swing

I want to draw a line between different components in a JPanel, but the line should be a component, ie, it can be clicked, highlighted, selected and deleted instead of just painting a line in a panel, is there anything like this or I must implement it by myself. And if I must implement it, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to use prepared things like `JSeparator`, But I found the best way by myself and I implement it. I used a `JLayeredPane` for my container. I add my own `JPanel` behind the all layers and override its `paint()` method. in `paint()` method I used Java2D to draw a curve between Components on higher layers in `JLayeredPane`. You can see the result in below.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `JSeparator`. But you'll have to implement the click, highlighting, selection and deletion yourself. A JSeparator is just use to... separate sections in a panel.

If you mean that all these operations should be available when designing your GUI in a wysiwyg editor like NetBeans Matisse, then JSeparator is just what you need.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I want to know that whether JSeparator can be diagonal or not. and is it enough to override its paint method?

Comment: How about reading its documentation : http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSeparator.html. No, it can't be diagonal. paint is not the method to override for a JComponent. paintComponent is the one. But you won't be able to do all you want by just overriding paintComponent.